# How do you say "spread something like seeds by casting a wide net by throwing" idiomatically?

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

How do you say "spread something like seeds by casting a wide net by throwing"?

I can't think of anything.

The only phrase I can think of is "spread the seeds widely", but it doesn't sound idiomatic or grammatical.

Comment: The most idiomatic way to say it is to use a word you already used: [**cast the seeds**](https://www.google.com/search?q="cast+the+seeds").

Comment: Before radio and TV, **broadcast** meant to sow seeds by scattering them by hand. https://www.slideshare.net/PoLillian/the-parable-of-the-sower-35073354

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiomatic way of saying this is to **scatter seeds**.

> [**scatter**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scatter), verb
> (*transitive*) To distribute loosely as by sprinkling.

Comment: Hmm, wait, I never heard "farmers scattered seeds". Is there a verb for putting seeds on a line instead of scattering?

Comment: @Sayaman, farmers would **plant a field** by **sowing seeds** (probably with a machine). "Scattering" means to take a handful of seeds and cast them out by flicking your wrist.

Comment: @Sayaman: Farmers **drill** seeds in a line.